# Flutter: 2 positional arguments expeted

Tags: flutter

I have a problem in my code, I try to explain it as briefly as possible, practically: I wanted to redirect with the initalroute command only that in the code it gives me the problem I wrote in the title. I just want to make sure that when I open the web app, as soon as I log in and go to the main page on the url it says / login / dashboard.

//first part of code

```
  initialRoute: '/',
  // Redirect a /login
  //Capire come fare redirect a /dashboard
  routes: {
    '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
    '/dashboard': (context) => HomePage(), //here is the error 2 positional argument(s)
  },
```

//second part (homepage)

```
factory HomePage.fromBase64(String jwt) => HomePage(
  jwt,
  json.decode(
      ascii.decode(base64.decode(base64.normalize(jwt.split(".")[1])))));

 final String jwt;
 final Map<String, dynamic> payload;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
  elevation: 0.3,
  centerTitle: false,
  title: Row(
    children: [
      Text(
        'wow',
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline6!
            .copyWith(color: Colors.orange, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      )
    ],
  ),
));
```

}
}
hope someone can give me a solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you get is because `HomePage` takes two arguments, but you don't pass any, this happens because they are positional arguments, meaning they must be passed, you can make them optional by wrapping them with `{ }` in `HomePage` constructor

it will be something like this:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  // add {} here to make it optional
  const HomePage({
    Key key,
    this.jwt,
    this.payload,
  })  : super(key: key);

  final String jwt;
  final Map<String, dynamic> payload;
}
```

this will fix the problem for sure, but might not do what you want, because you want both the jwt and payload to be passed when HomePage is created, but this will make `HomePage` can be created without it complaining it's missing arguments, so another solution is to actually pass the arguments in HomePage constructor like this:

```
routes: {
    '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
    '/dashboard': (context) => HomePage(/** pass the arguments here*/), 
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show me where I should put the {} in the code?

Comment: thanks, if i wanted to pass the arguments, what should i write inside?

Comment: your jwt and payload

Comment: the play load I don't know what to write to it, the jwt either, because it is a code that is generated every time a user logs in

Comment: well you shouldn't pass them in constructor, you should retrieve them from server or storage

Comment: would you know how to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236813/discussion-between-michael-soliman-and-lorenzo-borgato).

Comment: Will you answer me in private chat?